# e.preventDefault not working on laravel 5.7

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, laravel

I'm doing chat app Laravel 5.7 and having a challenge with jQuery AJAX function.

I'm using PHP version 7.1.9 with 3.x version of jQuery.

Here's my form with the AJAX request:

```
<form action="/channels/{{$channel->id}}" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="channel_id" value="{{$channel->id}}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}" />
  <input type="text" name="msg" class="form-control msg" />
  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="btn send-msg" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
      }
    });
    $(".send-msg").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var user_id = $("input[name='user_id']").val();
      var channel_id = $("input[name='channel_id']").val();
      var user = $("input[name='user']").val();
      var msg = $("input[name='msg']").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/channels/{{$channel->id}}",
        data: {
          msg: msg,
          user: user,
          channel_id: channel_id,
          user_id: user_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data.success);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

And my PHP code:

```
public function sendmessage(Request $request){
  $message = new Messages();
  $message->channel_id = $request->channel_id;
  $message->user_id = $request->user_id;
  $message->username = $request->user;
  $message->message = $request->msg;
  $message->save();
  return response()->json(['success'=>'Got Simple Ajax Request.']);
}
```

Normally, it should post an alert with data, but actually, it redirect me to `/channels/{id}` with `json : success: Got Simple Ajax Request`

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finnally found the solution ! It was not from the ajax but the form, in fact in my form I had this:

```
<form action="/channels/{{$channel->id}}" method="POST">
```

I replace it by

```
<form>
```

And now it works perfectly ! Thanks everybody ! Love ya !

Answer (score 1):

Since you only attached the `event` handler to the `submit` button, your form will still follow the default behaviour of form submission when other events such as pressing the `enter` key after changing the input value are fired.

To solve this, instead of attaching the event listener to the button, it's better to listen for the `submit` event on the form itself.

> This will cover both the form `submit` and button `click` events.

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // if e.preventDefault() doesn't work, try `return false`

    // your remaining code here
});
```

Comment: Instead of `e.preventDefault()` can you try `return false;` inside the `submit` handler instead and see if it works.

Comment: Also you can remove input type submit and add a simple span or button with onclick property.

Comment: Even with return false; I got the same issue,